# Make the options of the 2nd select box populate depending on the 1st. Both are PHP arrays

Tags: php, mysql

I have two innoDB tables in my database named **customers** and **vessels**. I also have a form with 2 select boxes one having the column: **company_name** of table: **customers** as options, and the other having the column: **vessel_name** of table: **vessels**.

What i want to do is make the options of the 2nd select box populate according to the customer's company_name chosen in the 1st select box.

Finally please take into consideration that i am a complete newbie in Javascript and jQuery and thats why i am asking here how can i achieve the above result.

The form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

        <form name="ypo" method="post">

        <select name="company_name">
        <?php
        foreach($pelates as $pelend) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $pelend->company_name; ?>"><?php echo $pelend->company_name; ?></option>
        <?php
        }
            ?>
        </select>


        <select name="vessel">
        <?php
        foreach($ploia as $end) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $end->vessel_name; ?>"><?php echo $end->vessel_name; ?></option>
        <?php
        }
            ?>
        </select>

    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

The php to make the above form work :

```
    <?php

// For customers
$sqlpelates = "SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY company_name";

if($pelat = $db->query($sqlpelates)) {

$pelates = array();

    while($pelate = $pelat->fetch_object()) {
        $pelates[] = $pelate;
    }

$pelat->free();

}

// For vessels
$sqlploia = "SELECT * FROM vessels ORDER BY vessel_name";

if($plo = $db->query($sqlploia)) {

$ploia = array();

    while($ploi = $plo->fetch_object()) {
        $ploia[] = $ploi;
    }

$plo->free();

}

?>
```

**UPDATE**: Below is the single .php page where i am trying to achieve the above result:

```
<?php

require 'db/connect.php';
//check if this is an ajax call
$ajax = isset($_POST['ajax']) ? $_POST['ajax'] : false;
if (!$ajax) {
  // if not then this is a fresh page that needs everything
  $sqlpelates = "SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY company_name";
  if ($pelat=$db->query($sqlpelates)) {
    $pelates = array();
    while($pelate=$pelat->fetch_object()) $pelates[] = $pelate;
    $pelat->free();
  }
}
// modify the query to filter out only what your ajax request wants
$where = $ajax ? ' WHERE company_name="'.$_POST['companyName'].'"' : '';
// you need to make sure to escape the incoming variable $_POST['company_name']
$sqlploia = 'SELECT * FROM vessels'.$where.' ORDER BY vessel_name';
if ($plo=$db->query($sqlploia)) {
  $ploia = array();
  while($ploi=$plo->fetch_object()) $ploia[] = $ploi;
  $plo->free();
}
// the secret sauce... and some very bad programming, this should be done some other way
if ($ajax) {
  // set the type, so the client knows what the server returns
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  // output what the client asked for: an array of vessels in JSON format
  echo json_encode($ploia);
  // kill the script, this is all the client wants to know
  exit;
}



?>  

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="jquery.js">

// Your code goes here.
// jQuery must be loaded already
$(function(){
  var
    // put the target php script
    url = 'http://prinseapals-marine.com/filing/drop_down.php',
    form=$('form[name="ypo"]'), company, vessels;
  company = {
    // I prefer using native DomElements sometimes
    selectBox : $(form).find('select[name="company_name"]')[0],
    onSelect : function () {
      var
        idx = company.selectBox.selectedIndex,
        data;
      // if user selected an empty option, clear and return
      if (idx === -1) {vessels.clearBox();return;}
      // setup the data 
      data = {"ajax":1,"company_name":company.selectBox[idx].value};
      // your script now has $_GET['ajax'], $_GET['company_name']
      $.post(url,data,vessels.fillBox,'json');
      // vessels.fillbox will be executed when your php script returns
    }
  };
  vessels = {
    // I prefer using native DomElements sometimes
    selectBox : $(form).find('select[name="vessel"]')[0],
    // a handy method for clearing options
    clearBox : function () {$(this.selectBox).empty()},
    // called upon completion of the ajax request
    fillBox : function (arrayOfVessels) {
      // clear current contents
      $(this.selectBox).empty();
      // for each element in the array append a new option to the vessel selector
      arrayOfVessels.forEach(function(v){
        $(vessels.selectBox).append('<option value="'+v+'">'+v+'</option>');
      });
    }
  };
  // add a listener to the company selector
  $(company.selectBox).change(company.onSelect);
});
</script>


        <form name="ypo" method="post">

        <select name="company_name">
        <?php
        foreach($pelates as $pelend) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $pelend->company_name; ?>"><?php echo $pelend->company_name; ?></option>
        <?php
        }
            ?>
        </select>


        <select name="vessel">
        <?php
        foreach($ploia as $end) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $end->vessel_name; ?>"><?php echo $end->vessel_name; ?></option>
        <?php
        }
            ?>
        </select>

    </form>

    </body>
```

**FINAL-UPDATE** :

test.php:

```
<?php

require 'db/connect.php';
$cus = array();
if($cterm = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `customers`")) {
    while($cterm2 = $cterm->fetch_object()) {
        $cus[] = $cterm2;
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="form1" name="myform"> 
    <select name="selection" onchange="load('bdiv', 'test2.php');">
    <?php
    foreach($cus as $c) {
    ?>
    <option value="<? echo $c->company_name ?>"><? echo $c->company_name ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </select>

    <div id="bdiv"></div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

test.js:

```
function load (thediv, thefile) {
    // body...
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById(thediv).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open('GET', thefile+'?selection='+document.myform.selection.value, true);
    xmlhttp.send();


}
```

test2.php:

```
<?php

require 'db/connect.php';

if (isset($_GET['selection'])) {
    # code...
    $selection = $_GET['selection'];
}

$ves = array();
    if ($vterm = $db->query(
        "SELECT `vessel_name` FROM `vessels` WHERE `company_name` = '$selection'")) {
        while ($vterm2 = $vterm->fetch_object()) {
            $ves[] = $vterm2;
        }

    } else {
    echo 'Please type a customer name.';
    }
?>

<select>
    <?php
    foreach($ves as $v) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $v->vessel_name ?>" ><?php echo $v->vessel_name ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the first time I see this asked but I will dive in

**Warning:** this answer has javascript, with jQuery. I will also append a php file afterwards with some changes to allow the same script to be called for the ajax request

```
// jQuery must be loaded already
$(function(){
  var
    // put the target php script
    url = 'http://localhost/test/stackoverflow.php',
    form=$('form[name="ypo"]'), company, vessels;
  company = {
    // I prefer using native DomElements sometimes
    selectBox : $(form).find('select[name="company_name"]')[0],
    onSelect : function () {
      var
        idx = company.selectBox.selectedIndex,
        data;
      // if user selected an empty option, clear and return
      if (idx === -1) {vessels.clearBox();return;}
      // setup the data 
      data = {"ajax":1,"company_name":company.selectBox[idx].value};
      // your script now has $_GET['ajax'], $_GET['company_name']
      $.post(url,data,vessels.fillBox,'json');
      // vessels.fillbox will be executed when your php script returns
    }
  };
  vessels = {
    // I prefer using native DomElements sometimes
    selectBox : $(form).find('select[name="vessel"]')[0],
    // a handy method for clearing options
    clearBox : function () {$(this.selectBox).empty()},
    // called upon completion of the ajax request
    fillBox : function (arrayOfVessels) {
      // clear current contents
      $(this.selectBox).empty();
      // for each element in the array append a new option to the vessel selector
      arrayOfVessels.forEach(function(v){
        $(vessels.selectBox).append('<option value="'+v+'">'+v+'</option>');
      });
    }
  };
  // add a listener to the company selector
  $(company.selectBox).change(company.onSelect);
});
```

The logic behind the js code is to allow user interaction. When the user makes a selection a request is fired to the server and the response is processed in the client and populates your 2nd `<select>`

Now, a ***modified*** version of your php script (warning: this works with the template I append next)

```
<?php
// your model, check for whitespaces outside php tags, do not allow output yet
require 'db/connect.php';
// check if this is an ajax call
$ajax = isset($_POST['ajax']) ? $_POST['ajax'] : false;
if (!$ajax) {
  // required for the template
  $pelates = array();
  // if not then this is a fresh page that needs everything
  $sqlpelates = "SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY company_name";
  if ($pelat=$db->query($sqlpelates)) {
    while($pelate=$pelat->fetch_object()) $pelates[] = $pelate;
    $pelat->free();
  }
} else {
  // modify the query to filter out only what your ajax request wants
  $where = ' WHERE company_name="'.$_POST['companyName'].'"';
  // required for the ajax request
  $ploia = array();
  // you need to make sure to escape the incoming variable $_POST['company_name']
  $sqlploia = 'SELECT * FROM vessels'.$where.' ORDER BY vessel_name';
  if ($plo=$db->query($sqlploia)) {
    while($ploi=$plo->fetch_object()) $ploia[] = $ploi;
    $plo->free();
  }
  // the secret sauce... and some very bad programming, this should be done some other way
  // set the type, so the client knows what the server returns
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  // output what the client asked for: an array of vessels in JSON format
  echo json_encode($ploia);
  // kill the script, this is all the client want's to know
  exit;
}
?>
```

Next comes a modified version of your html template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Your title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="ypo" method="post">
      <select name="company_name"><?php
        foreach($pelates as $p) echo '<option value="'.$p->company_name.'">'.$p->company_name.'</option>';
      ?></select>
      <!-- leave empty, we will populate it when the user selects a company -->
      <select name="vessel"></select>
    </form>
    <!-- add jQuery lib here, either your own or from a CDN; this is google's version 2.0.3 -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- The code should be in a seperate file, load here if you want (but after jQuery lib) -->
    <script src="your/javascript/file.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ok, now some pointers

- you should be carefull with the php script I left there, there are other ways of doing what I intended which are cleaner and easier to maintain
- the javascript is not the best, there are better solutions out there so be sure to check those out as well
- If you do not understand parts of any of the scripts don't hesitate to ask
- **Beware any whitespace**, do not allow any output before the php script, this is very important. All output should be left to the template

I hope this has been helpfull

Comment: Is the modified version of my php script intended to work straight with the above form in the same page lets say steve.php  ? Cause if it is it doesnt work:(

Comment: My testing indicates it still isn't complete. I still have to edit the php file, sorry, it'll take another minute or so...

Comment: It should work now... change `url = 'http:...'` to your target `steve.php(?)`, and don't forget to escape `company_name` before it gets into the query, a safety precaution. I can also put up a special `ajax.php` script that would handle the request

Comment: Ihave updeted my initial post with your solution can you plz check if i got it all correct cause it still doesnt work for me.Perhaps i am loading jquery the wrong way or because i only know HTML and PHP i cant understand if i must use both of your codes in different files or both in one can u take a min and check it out for me ? Btw really thanks for all your help. Also i have downloaded jquery and put it in my root dir as jquery.js

Comment: ok, I'll append an html template like you have in your question box. The template will include the javascript files where I think they should be. It works fine for me in my testing environment so if there is any problem let me know

Comment: If this did not work for you please leave feedback, otherwise mark as answered

Comment: Really thank you hanzo2001 for all the time you invested in my problem your solution not only worked as a charm but made me  understand also the whole thing better and eventually i found a solution of my own which i am appending as a final-update in my initial post.Thumbs up thanks again for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax for this, Pass your company id to the javascript

```
<script>
function showCustomer(str)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myresult").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php?q="+str,true); // Pass value to another page Here->test
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

<select name="company_name" onchange="showCustomer(this.value)">
    <?php
    foreach($pelates as $pelend) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $pelend->company_name; ?>"><?php echo $pelend->company_name; ?></option>
    <?php
    }
        ?>
    </select>

<div id="myresult">


</div>
```

Now On test.php Simply Call Value & put select box,

```
<?php
$q = $_GET['q'];

// Here fetch values for particular q(company name)

// put select box
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that the post method i am using in my form is POST already edited.

Comment: Please kindly mention any changes needed to the above and if this could be done without ajax in any simpler javascript way.