# PHP select boxes depending on each other

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a select box with options from PHP variables. If you choose option1 the second select box should get other options than you would choose option2. I read that I can do this with javascript, but I don't know how to insert php variables into javascript? Does someone have any idea?

Comment: I have answered this question a couple of times. You should look for them

Answer (score 1):

Here, one of my answers some time ago https://stackoverflow.com/a/20271096/2733184 with a congrats for explaining how it worked

### EDIT: new info from Author

> How can I do it only with PHP and without AJAX?

Because PHP resides on the server. You will have to break up your form submission process in 2 stages:

1. First form is a shell that only provides some info and the first select element
2. Second form is the actual submit with the result of the first submit hardcoded into it

This limitation means that your forms are still 2 static pieces of HTML with no interactivity, and from my perspective you *want* interactivity.

It is my recomendation that you do not use this approach. It is for cases like this that Ajax is *The Best* candidate.

Comment: uh... link-only answers are not good no matter if they lead inside SO, or outside. If the question is a duplicate, flag it as such.

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm sorry I'm such a newbie at this, I couldn't find the send-private-message button. I don't know how to flag. DARNIT, just in front of my eyes!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you have like 100k of data altogether, it can be included in the page as a json array (use json_encode from php) and then you can implement the switching logic in javascript.

If you have more than this, or if your records come from a non-listable source (like a query from something big), you can do an ajax call after the first select, and then you again have more options to go on: load the second select's contents into json, or (maybe this is more convenient for you) use something like

```
$("#mydiv").load("selects.php?first=3")
```

to load the whole html of the next select tag. This gives you the extra ability to make not only selects but any kind of next-level choice, depending on what the user has chosen first.

WITHOUT AJAX:

Apart from what I suggested in my first paragraph :), yes, there are ways to avoid AJAX.  But why would you?...  Something similar to AJAX is the iframe technique, you can use that, which would mean you call a script in a hidden iframe and do a

```
<script> parent.doSomething(myNewData); </script>
```

call in it. But that's basically the same principle.  YOU NEED THE INFORMATIONS FROM SERVER SIDE, right?...  If you don't, of course you can do it with Javascript only.  But if you need something from server, you'll have to go ask for it.  Client has to initiate communication to server, then server will download new information for the second dropdown.

TO RECAP THIS WHOLE THING,

1. You can download every necessary part right together with your page,
2. You can use AJAX to download it later,
3. You can use iframes to download it later.
4. You can ... well, you can request info with a runtime-inserted script tag.

But 4 is the dark side.
1-2-3 will work nicely.

Answer (score -1):

A good way to do it should be to use AJAX.

This can also be done with PHP.

**AJAX method:**

By calling an AJAX event on first drop down change.

Pass first drop down's selected value to AJAX.

The backend PHP code will return `<select>` drop down's HTML.

**Pseudo code:**

```
<select name="sel" id="sel" onchange="populateSecondDropDown()">
<option value="1">Test</option>
</select>

<div id="sel2Container">
<select name="sel" id="sel"></select>
</div>

<script>
function populateSecondDropDown() {
 $.ajax({
  // Expect a `mycustomtype` back from server
  url: 'backend.php?sel='+$("#sel").val(),
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
   $("sel2Container").html(data.sel2);
  }
});
}
<script>
```

PHP backend:

```
if (isset($_POST['sel'])) {
 //.. Your logic to populate second drop down.
 $dropDown = '<select name="sel2" id="sel2">
<option value="1">Test 2</option>
</select>';
 echo json_encode($dropDown);
}
```

Comment: You don't always need AJAX to get data from the server...

Comment: @JanDvorak he gave one answer "_You can..._", doesn't necessarily mean it's the only answer

Comment: @hanzo2001 It's still a link-mostly answer to a question that probably should be closed.

Comment: @JanDvorak is it _bad_ if the link points to someplace other than SO? I guess you could be right on this one ( ¬_¬)

Comment: @hanzo2001 the criteria on link-only answers is: "does the answer say _anything_ if the link dies? This only says "you can use AJAX; just listen to the changes on the drop down". I don't find this level of quality acceptable.

Comment: How can I do it only with PHP and without AJAX?

Comment: You can do it by redirecting the page on drop down change and passing id to it in the query string.

Comment: @JanDvorak ok, I guess you're right and I should start enforcing better quality in the answers. Thanks. To the author: only PHP means you need to do 2 sequential posts, I'll expand in my own single link answer

Answer (score -1):

PHP is a Server Side Language and Javascript a Client Side Language.

You can't insert php variables into javascript. AJAX is the true way. You need to make with javascript/AJAX a request to the server, with the value from selectbox 1 to load the Values for the box2 after the first selection. The same way with box3,4,...

Sry for my bad enghlish.

Comment: Of course you can insert PHP variables in javascript... it's the other way around that can't be done.

Comment: @JanDvorak this is the problem with my enghlish. i mean that you can't use the php variables with javascript source. what you can do, is to insert the values from the php variables into the JS source.